# Ruby tools to set up a personal website

Tags: ruby, development-environment

I'm trying to find a good set of tools to be able to implement my personal website.

The must have:

1. The site or its generator must be Ruby based
2. It must be easy to deploy and maintain

The nice to have:

1. It should be typographically clean and beautiful
2. It should have html5/css3 capabilities

I was thinking about having a go directly with rails 3 but it seemed somehow overkill.

**EDIT**

The content will be a mix of portfolio and blogging.

What are you rubysts using? is it working well?

Comment: sintra or padrino is your choice

Comment: maybe you can specify which content you plan to put on your website. Do you need blogging features? Portfolio? Comments?

Comment: "Typographically clean and beautiful" and "have html5/css3 capabilities" are entirely independent of what framework you use.

Comment: @Rein, totally agree just would like to know if there was something that already integrates these

Comment: Just bumped into [Nesta CMS](http://nestacms.com/) anyone using it?

Comment: @tommasop I would recommend using scss/compass with whatever framework you want for great typography and css3 support. Sounds like a static site generator or a simple RESTful framework like Sinatra (Padrino) would work for you.

Comment: Interesting [article](http://webexpedition18.com/articles/create-attractive-web-typography-with-css3-and-lettering-js/) on CSS3 typography

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You didn't really specify how exactly your site is going to be in terms of static/dynamic content etc, so all one can really do is list some options:

- [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/)
- [Padrino](http://www.padrinorb.com/)
- [Ramaze](http://ramaze.net/)
- [nanoc](http://nanoc.ws/)
- [Stasis](http://stasis.me/)
- [Camping](https://camping.github.io/camping.io/) (thanks fl00r)

At work we use Rails, for my private projects I tend to use Sinatra and am very happy with its minimalism. I am however planning to do something with Padrino soon, since it seems to be positioned in a nice niche between Sinatra and Rails.

Comment: others here: http://ruby-toolbox.com/categories/static_website_generation.html

Comment: Thanks! Updated some of the other links too and removed some unmaintained projects.

Answer (score 4):

I'm currently using [Nanoc](http://nanoc.stoneship.org/), and I'd definitely recommend starting with a static site generator. This almost completely cuts out many types of issue. It also enables you to store your content as text files on a filesystem, rather than dealing with a database and special editor interfaces.

If you need server-side programming then move up to something that uses Git as the storage, again really to avoid locking your content into a database.

It's well worth looking at [Compass](http://compass-style.org/) to help you with the CSS - Compass will work with whatever you choose. Compass does require you to spend a little time learning it, but can makes CSS much easier in the longer-term. For example, it has helpers that let you set up CSS3 effects.

Comment: +1 for nanoc. Chris Eppstein the creator of Compass uses it for his blog http://chriseppstein.github.com/.

Answer (score 3):

[Jekyll](https://github.com/mojombo/jekyll) seems to be what the cool kids use these days. It's a generator, not a CMS.

You can find lots of "open source" sites online with various setups (see [here](https://github.com/henrik/henrik.nyh.se))

Answer (score 0):

**My Solution**

After **too much** thinking I ended up using [Nesta CMS](http://nestacms.com/) as envisioned in [this Peepcode blog 
article](http://blog.peepcode.com/tutorials/2010/about-this-blog).

Actually I use a home made scss version of http://semantic.gs and the html5 boilerplate layout.

Nesta is now plugin capable and has two wonderful plugins available:

1. [Blogazine](https://github.com/gma/nesta-plugin-blogazine) which helps you obtain the peepcode blog solution
2. [Maldini](http://bweslake.org/research/resources/maldini) which generates citations and reference lists from BibTeX files

Thanks everyone for sharing your thoughts.